# Ajax PUT request failing

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, form-data

I am making an ajax PUT request and including all the required fields for the request. I am still getting 400 error.

This is my formdata

```
var formData = new FormData()
        var politician_id = this.props.image_reducer.politicianList[this.props.image_reducer.selectedPoliticianRow].person.id

        console.log("id is "+ politician_id)
        var politician =  {
            "description": document.getElementById('description-input').value,
            "political_party": document.getElementById('party-input').value,
            "constituency": document.getElementById('constituency-input').value,
            "positions": document.getElementById('positions-input').value,
        }
        formData.append("name", document.getElementById('name-input').value)
        formData.append("dob", document.getElementById('birth-input').value)
        formData.append("born_location",document.getElementById("birth-location-input").value)
        formData.append("current_location",document.getElementById('current-location-input').value)
        formData.append("description", document.getElementById('description-input').value)
        formData.append("father_name", document.getElementById('father-input').value)
        formData.append("mother_name", document.getElementById('mother-input').value)
        formData.append("partner_name", document.getElementById('name-input').value)
        formData.append("religion", document.getElementById('religion-input').value)
        formData.append("caste", document.getElementById('caste-input').value)
        formData.append("occupation", "politician")
        formData.append("education", document.getElementById('occupation-input').value)
        formData.append("politician", JSON.stringify(politician))
```

This is how I am making request

```
var settings = {
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": url,
            "type": "PUT",
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            "credentials": 'include',
            "headers": {
                Authorization: "Token " + token
            },
            "data": data,
            success:( response, textStatus, jQxhr )=> {
                console.log("info updated")

            }
        }
        $.ajax(settings).done((response) => {
            console.log("info updated success")
        });
```

This is the error I am getting

[image]
[image]

It is perfectly ok from my backend side if I leave "actor" field. Please don't consider that to be a possible answer. I tried including "actor" also but still got same error.

What am I doing wrong? Am I making formdata in wrong manner?

**Update**

The JSON I am sending is (This is from console where I printed formdata)

[image]

Comment: In you `ajax` you have `"data": data`. What's `data`? It's not defined. Shouldn't it be `formData`?

Comment: It is formdata only. I am passing formdata as data. That is correct.

Comment: Could you provide the `json` that's being sent to the server in you `PUT` request?

Comment: @htshame have a look at the update in question. I have attached the json u asked

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the data is either not passed or not converted properly on the server side and hence the validation failure. In the request headers I can notice it is sending `multipart/form-data`.

Do update the `consumes` of your `RequestMapping` to allow `multipart/form-data` i.e. `consumes = { "multipart/form-data" }`

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: @ApurvG the answer is relevant for a Spring controller with RequestMapping. Can you tell more about your server side. What exactly it is expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Try sending your data as JSON:

```
var settings = {
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": url,
            "type": "PUT",
            processData: false,
            "credentials": 'include',
            "headers": {
                Authorization: "Token " + token
            },
            "data": data,
            "contentType":"application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success:( response, textStatus, jQxhr )=> {
                console.log("info updated")

            }
        }
        $.ajax(settings).done((response) => {
            console.log("info updated success")
        });
```

Comment: You might need to also do JSON.stringify(data) before you send it

Comment: Look at the update of my question. I have added the formdata which I am sending